# Light alternative to Sunspot for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search, sunspot

I really like Sunspot in Rails, but it adds way too much to my slug size on heroku (10mb to 33mb). Is there a good, much lighter alternative to Sunspot? I only need basic full text searching for two fields.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally put more data in your repo than you needed? You can exclude solr/**/* in your .gitignore. My decent sized sunspot-containing project is only 18mb total

Comment: @spike, I had solr/ in my gitignore. I replaced that with solr/**/* and that made the slug size even bigger (high 30's)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure whether heroku does it, but since it uses pg - I don't see why tsearch2 wouldn't work, best thing is, you shouldn't need any gems (so long as you aren't afraid to write a little SQL).

Comment: Yeah, my search requirements are so simple that some simple sql does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [meta-search](http://github.com/ernie/meta_search). I think for a little searching it is enough.

Answer (score 1):

The slug size is large because Sunspot includes a bundled instance of Solr, which is a large distribution. I believe the forthcoming 1.3 release of Sunspot splits this out into a separate gem, so the main Sunspot client gem will be a much more manageable size. 1.3 is currently out as a prerelease: https://rubygems.org/gems/sunspot/versions/1.3.0.rc4

Answer (score 0):

Check out the IndexTank add-on and the Tanker gem.